# the command wc's function

Tags: shell

I encouter many shell script in these days using command `wc` which is really awesome.For example:

1. For example, in the last 20 hours or so, 16 new users registered with FAS:
   `$ cat messages | grep  \

   'fedora-infrastructure:org.fedoraproject.prod.fas.user.create'|wc -l

   16 /*output*/`
2. calculate the lines of code in the `.` directory

   `find . -type f -exec cat '{}' \; | wc -l`

I'm a newbie to Linux,so I want to now what kind of amazing stuff `wc` can do(with other commands support) **not only basic usage come from man page**

Comment: By the way, (2) is just getting all lines from all files in the current directory node (tree segment.) Limit the file types matched to get a more accurate LOC count.

Answer (score 2):

(**Edit**: It sounds like you might benefit most from understanding [what pipes are, and how they work](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~mamrak/CIS762/pipes_lab_notes.html))

Try this on your command line:

```
man wc
```

It gives you the manual page for `wc`, with which you can find out all the things you can do with the tool.

And here are a few basic idioms / mental models to know when you are starting out learning Linux:

- `wc` is one tool. There are many tools you can directly interact with in your `[shell][2]`, such as: `ls` (lists contents of current directory), `pwd` (prints your current working directory), `date` (prints the current time), and more advanced ones such as `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, `tr`.
- The `|` syntax (but not `||`!) is called a "[pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)":

  - By default, commands can either read from `stdin` ([standard input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)) or read from file, or don't need to read anything at all (`ls`, for example, doesn't require input)
  - So when you do something like `ls | wc -l`, it's actually saying:

    - run `ls`
    - take the output of `ls`, which would normally be written to `stdout` (standard output), and "pipe it" directly into the `stdin` of `wc`, which, together with the `-l` option to `wc`, counts the number of lines.
- There is no exhaustive list of other commands that `wc` can interact with, due to the pipes-and-filters paradigm in shell languages. Anything you see something like `... | wc`, it just means that whatever output by the program before the `|` is fed to `wc` as input.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I want to know that how and when you use `wc` command ?some amazing combinations with other commands?

Comment: @ZhangYuan: give this a read: http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~mamrak/CIS762/pipes_lab_notes.html I think it'll make a lot more sense after =)

Answer (score 0):

Unix tools are designed to be very simple, things like `wc` are very good examples of this.

## wc = Word count

## wc -l = Line count

In unix you can direct output from one command to another using `|`

The idea is that you combine these small tools together to achieve results way beyond their individual capacities.

## find

Is a very powerful command with many options, but essentially finds filenames for files matching the predicates and options specified.

## man

`man` is a help system built into unix, just type `man wc` to get info about `wc` you can use it for most commands available from the command line, with only a few exceptions.

## Zsh, Antigen & Oh-My-Zsh

Unix is a lot easier with a good shell, and helpful tools. I recommend you use Zsh, the easy way to get this setup is to use [Antigen](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen) and [Oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) (Antigen will help install Oh-My-Zsh and a bunch of other tools, so follow it's instructions.)

Once you have it setup, you have Tab auto-completion, showing commmands, command options (for many tools, such as `git`, `find` etc... etc..)

This will very quickly transform the murky darkness of the shell into a vibrant environment to work in.

## How to learn cool combinations of commands?

Well, to get started, always remember you have basic looping and conditions available on the unix shell.

- loops

  - [while](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/while-loop.htm)
  - [for](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/for-loop.htm)
  - [until](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/until-loop.htm)
  - [select](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/select-loop.htm)
- conditions

  - [if](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/if-fi-statement.htm)
  - [case](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/case-esac-statement.htm)

These commands usually work with filename patterns, e.g. `*.txt` and also often work with piped `|` input.

For example, if you wanted to perform a complex operation, let's say rename a set of files replacing a given pattern:

```
for f in *; mv $a ${a/bak/}
```

Would remove the word `bak` from all the filenames in the current folder.\

## Hidden gold

There are two commands [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) and [`awk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) which are <strike>almost</strike> languages in their own right.  It is not necessary to know them inside out, and many things they do can be replicated by simpler commands, such as [`tr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29) and [`cut`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29). However, understanding how they basically work is a very handy thing to know. In fact, **Sed** and **Awk** are so powerful, they even have an O'Reilly book dedicated to them.

## Where to find examples of Unix command line awesomeness?

A good place to look for examples is [command-line fu](http://commandlinefu.com)

Good luck